# Matplotlib (Jupyter ipython) : Plotting does not work in MacOS Backend

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Background to the problem : I basically switched from Macbook pro 2015 to Macbook pro 2017 (from  `macOS Sierra 10.12.6` to `High Sierra 10.13.2`), and I copied everything from the old macbook with time machine.

I recently changed my computer and have tons of errors with matplotlib -.-
First problem was : **if I open a interactive figure and then close it (press the cross) then Jupyter would hang.**   I looked up on solution and basically the suggestions were to update everything, and so I did.

I am using

```
Jupyter 4.4.0
conda 4.3.30
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 11:07:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
```

my Previous computer,

```
conda 4.3.30
Jupyter 4.1.0
Python 2.7.11 | Annaconda custom(x86_64) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577) on darwin
```

I had previously matplotlib `1.5.1`, now I upgraded to `2.1.1` in hopes to fix the problem.

In my previous computer (which still works fine with matplotlib), I was using `MacOSX` backend (default) and it worked great for plotting. However, I am having great deal of problem with this one. First, the plotting would have just crashed the `jupyter`, now with all the updates at least it does not crash but now,  **`MacOSX` backend in does not even display the plot**
The cell just runs and nothing comes out.

Example :

```
import matplotlib
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print "backend : ", matplotlib.get_backend()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

output :

```
Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX
backend :  MacOSX
```

And no plot at all!

If I use `tkAgg` backend :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print "backend : ", matplotlib.get_backend()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()

backend :  TkAgg
```

It runs fine and plots the plot on new window but closing the plot now does not stop the cell from running. I have to stop it by keyboard or press stop on jupyter.

Am I missing something here? Anyway to fix this annoying thing in matplotlib?

Further :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

gives,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8c09ccc60eaa> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib
      2 matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 print "backend : ", matplotlib.get_backend()
      5 plt.plot(range(10))

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
    114 ## Global ##
    115 
--> 116 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
    117 
    118 _IP_REGISTERED = None

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.pyc in pylab_setup(name)
     58     # imports. 0 means only perform absolute imports.
     59     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name, globals(), locals(),
---> 60                              [backend_name], 0)
     61 
     62     # Things we pull in from all backends

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py in <module>()
      8 
      9 from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
---> 10 from .backend_qt4 import (
     11     QtCore, _BackendQT4, FigureCanvasQT, FigureManagerQT, NavigationToolbar2QT)
     12 from .backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAggBase

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py in <module>()
     16 from matplotlib.widgets import SubplotTool
     17 
---> 18 from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
     19 
     20 from .backend_qt5 import (

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py in <module>()
    148     # have been changed in the above if block
    149     if QT_API in [QT_API_PYQT, QT_API_PYQTv2]:  # PyQt4 API
--> 150         from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    151 
    152         try:

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is save the image to file and then open it up by `PIL`

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.save('fig.png')

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('fig.png')
img.show()
```